# How to remove od logs from serilog mongodb sink's table?

Tags: serilog

For the `RollingFile` sink there's Retention policy controlled by the `retainedFileCountLimit` parameter. I can see there's no such thing for the `MongoDb` sink, so I was wondering is there some reasonable workaround? I can only think of querying this table as any other in my app db and deleting the old records, but that definitely doesn't look like a good approach to me.

Comment: Doesn't `MongoDBCapped` sink do exactly that?